# SimpleModal Closing with Transition on overlay but not on X click

Tags: simplemodal

So I have a page that lives here:
http://testing.bistromd.com/new-media

If you scroll down the screen to the magazine section you will see one called "National Culinary Review". Click on the image of the cover and the modal will fire with all of the proper timings and transitions. It will also close correctly with the transitions and timings when you click anywhere outside of the modal on the overlay.

What DOES NOT work is when you click on the "X" button in the upper right of the modal box. Then the modal just vanishes instantly with NO transitions. Here is the relevant Code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#cr > a').click(function() {
      $("#crModal").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn(300, function () {
          dialog.container.fadeIn(10, function () {
            dialog.data.fadeIn(200);
          });
        });
        dialog.overlay.one('click', function () {
          dialog.data.fadeOut(200, function () {
            dialog.container.slideUp(10, function () {
              dialog.overlay.fadeOut(300, function () {
                $.modal.close();
              });
            });
          });
        });
      }});
    });
</script>
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On [SimpleModal's project page](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/), Eric gives an example of using the onClose event to do some animation, similar to how you're using the onOpen event now. Here's the example he provides:

```
$("#element-id").modal({onClose: function (dialog) {
    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close(); // must call this!
            });
        });
    });
}});
```

Comment: Yea, that's where I got the code above from originally, but that doesn't really help. my problem is getting that to function WITHIN the code you see above. I need what is already working above I just need the fade that is working on 'dialog.overlay.one' to also work when you hit the close.png...

Comment: You're calling $("#crModal").modal(), passing it an object. That object has one property, named "onOpen", and it's value is a function that should be called when the 'open' event happens. This code in this answer shows calling that same function with an object that has an "onClose" event handler. Pass an object with both properties and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ok, so HOW, exactly do I do that? What is the separator for the two properties? I am terrible with syntax...

Comment: `$("#crModal").modal({ onOpen: function(dialog){ ... }, onClose: function(dialog){ ... });`

Comment: I just keep getting syntax errors, is there any way you could take the code above, and copy paste the complete solution. I tried every permutation and kept getting unexpected tokens...